# User specific hostname

Tags: linux, networking, freebsd, network-interface, routing

I have a linux and bsd system with multiple (virtual) network interfaces.
On those systems there are multiple users. Each user should use its own interface and therefore address.

Is it possible to change the return value of `2 gethostname`? This is the method that java uses to determine the local bind address, if no other was given.

I know about the environment variable `$HOSTALIASES` which (as far as U understabd) will not help with local address. Also, `man 2 hostname` does not mention the `$HOST` variable.

Is there a way to trick java (or any other tool using `2 gethostname`) to use my specific interface address for default bindings?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934027/process-local-override-of-name-resolution